# Angular JS ng-if not working within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects in scope, which I'm looping over with ng-repeat. I want to filter out some elements based on their values, but it seems like ng-if is completely ignored.

I've set up this simple plunk to illustrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/Aj0hpZQTfnkQ6BYG8DRb.
Here's the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.events = [
    {key: "ClassName", value: "exception", age:12},
    {key: "Message", value: "oops", age: 25},
    {key: "Stack", value: null, age: 35}
    ]
});
```

And the HTML template:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="event in events" ng-if="event.age > 20">
        [{{$index + 1}}] {{event.key}}: {{event.value}} - {{event.age}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

The `ng-if` directive is supposed to filter out the first element of the array, bit it is displayed anyway. What have I missed that ignores the ng-if?

Comment: "The ng-if directive is supposed to filter", no its not, it suppose to decide whether the whole element will be rendered or not, voted for CD..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the right way would be using a filter, for example:

```
<li ng-repeat="event in events | filter:greaterThan">
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qy3BVEogEgGivtqel73b?p=preview

Comment: I didn't know that function call syntax. Thx!

Comment: How about creating a reusable custom filter instead of attaching a function to the scope that compares hardcoded values, `item.age` and `20`. Take a look at this: http://plnkr.co/edit/h8Hm6JKm9WOZLHSMnc8R?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

[I've updated your Plunkr to solve your issue using the code below.](http://plnkr.co/edit/MKd7rgadGyIfCZRR8Jiq?p=preview)

I frequently use two custom angular modules, `FilterIncludeIf` and `UtilCompare` to provide `ng-if`-like functionality to `ng-repeat`s.

`FilterIncludeIf` has `UtilCompare` as a dependency and takes two arguments. The first is the comparison operator in string form (`">="` in your case).

The second is an `Object`. The *keys* should be set to the keys of the individual objects returned from the `ng-repeat` statement (`customer` in the example below) whose values you'd like to compare. The *values* should be set to the value you'd like to compare against.

Looking at `example-snippet.html`, `includeIf` ends up filtering `customers.all` and ensuring that the only `customer`s that are rendered are ones where all of the following statements are `true`.

```
customer[firstname] != customers.all.current.data.firstname`
customer[lastname] != customers.all.current.data.lastname`
customer[email] != customers.all.current.data.email`
```

**example-snippet.html**

```
<li 
    ng-repeat="customer in customers.all | filter:query | includeIf : '!=' : {
        firstname   : customers.current.data.firstname, 
        lastname    : customers.current.data.lastname,
        email       : customers.current.data.email, 
    }" 
    class="tab"
    >
    <div class="info">
        <h4 class="subheader name">
            {{customer.firstname}}&nbsp;{{customer.lastname}}
        </h4>
        {{customer.email}}
    </div>
</li>
```

**Filter - includeIf**

```
angular
.module('FilterIncludeIf', [
    'UtilCompare'
])  
.filter('includeIf', function (compare) {
    return function (items, comparator, attrs) {
        var filteredInput = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i],
                numOfAttrs = 0,
                numOfMatchedAttrs = 0;
            for (var key in attrs) {
                numOfAttrs++
                var value = attrs[key],
                    comparison = compare
                        .these(item[key], value)
                        .by(comparator)
                        .eval();

                if (comparison) numOfMatchedAttrs++;
            }
            if (numOfAttrs == numOfMatchedAttrs) filteredInput.push(item);
        }

        return filteredInput
    };
});
```

**Factory - compare**

```
angular
.module('UtilCompare', [])
.factory('compare', function () {
    var _by = undefined,
        _a = undefined,
        _b = undefined;

    var comparators = {
        '>'     : function(c, d) { return c > d },
        '<'     : function(c, d) { return c < d },
        '>='    : function(c, d) { return c >= d },
        '<='    : function(c, d) { return c <= d },
        '!='    : function(c, d) { return c != d },
        '!=='   : function(c, d) { return c !== d },
        '=='    : function(c, d) { return c == d },
        '==='   : function(c, d) { return c === d },
    }

    function by (comparator) {
        _by = comparator;
        return this
    }

    function these (a, b) {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        return this
    }

    function eval () {
        return comparators[_by](_a, _b);
    }

    return {
        by     : by,
        these  : these,
        eval   : eval
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is an actual [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09).

Filters can be applied on expressions (like the repeat) and will return a list containing only items that fulfills the criteria of the filter. So in this case I think you would do.

```
  <li ng-repeat="event in events | maxAge:20">
    ...
  </li>
```

Note that maxAge is not one of the default filters (you can find them to the left in the [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)), you would have to create one on your own unless you can fit it into the existing ones. But creating filters is really easy, they are just functions that take an input, do whatever logic they feel like and then return the new values.